# moving nested li elements using jquery snippet

Tags: jquery, list, move

```
<ul>
    <li><span> Level 1 </span>
         <ul>
             <li><span>Level 2</span> 
              <ul>
                   <li><span>Level 3</span></li>
                   <li><span>Level 3</span></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
         </li>
      <li><span> Level 1 </span>
         <ul>
             <li><span>Level 2</span></li>
          </ul>
      <li>
</ul>
```

In the above format i have a list item. I need to select a li and move it up or down on a button click. but i am facing problem while moving nested list. 
Inner li should be internally movable whereas the outer should be also movable along with the inner li's. Any help!!!

I am using

```
 selected.prev().before(selected); //for up
     selected.next().after(selected);   // for down
```

But all the time main li alone is moving. I do not know how to refer the children alone to move internally.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your event bubbles up every time you click on an inner 'li' and the complete li moves up instead of the children.

Use [event.stopPropogation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and bind it to the event on the click of your child 'li'

Comment: i am learning jquery.Not got used. Can u elaborate possibly with an example? Thanks..